# Jenkins feeding from team city

Tags: jenkins

I really like the idea of using jenkins to orchistrate the deployment and test of builds however i am stuck with team city for compilation at present.

Is there a way to have jenkins monitor a team city project and when new builds in team city complete grab the output artefacts as trigger for a new jenkins cycle?

Comment: Why are you trying to mix two different CI tools?

Comment: Can you not use Team City to manage your deployments as well?

Comment: I get that you can use one to do it all but, I don't want to. I want to use the Team City to build and unit test the appplication, and use jenkins for automated deployment. i used to use Cruise which is now call Go which does a much better job at managing the release pipeline.

Comment: @RobertBartley you say **want** to use two CI systems, but just out of technical curiosity - for what reason ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After installing Jenkins, you can use one of these:

1. [Monitor External Jobs](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Monitoring+external+jobs)
2. [FSTrigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/FSTrigger+Plugin)
3. [XTrigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/XTrigger+Plugin)

There are more [here](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plugins#Plugins-Buildtriggers).